What is the most appropriate HTTP status code for this message: "You must be 13 years or older to register"?
I am using the HTTP status code "403" for now but I want to know if there is a more appropriate HTTP status code.
{
   "status": 403,
   "message": {
      "en": "You must be 13 years or older to register.",
      "es": "Debes tener 13 años o más para registrarte."
   }
}

I want to know if there is a more appropriate HTTP status code for this situation.

There is status code 451, which might be the most accurate. But I agree with the answer below, 403 is acceptable and widely supported and understood.

I recommend you to continue with the Status Code (403) which you are using because here we have denied access due to restriction of the Age.
Also it is easily understand by client and browsers as well as it is as per the standard of HTTP.
